# How to kill a Zombie using blunt weapons?

Tags: warz-infestation-stories

I can't figure how to quickly dispatch zombies using blunt weapons, it appears that there is no way to tell if your hitting them in the head. Hitting them in the head is supposed to kill them faster, I ususally end up bashing them repeatedly for about 2 minutes before they die. **Any good tips for braining a zombie?**

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you talking about [this game](http://thewarz.com/)?

Comment: @fbueckert: Yes, I'm sure he is; it's a Day Z clone.  I can't believe this is the first question for it on the site, it's fairly popular..

Comment: @fbueckert currently wasting time at work, so can't check your link.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft i would say its definately derived from DayZ, but to call it a clone is like saying the battlefield series is a call of duty clone

Comment: Other way around, Battlefield came first ;)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Battlefield is better anyway, haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hit them in the head, I have to aim so that the center of my screen is about two zombie-heads to the up and right of their head *(yes, it feels like a lot)*.

You can tell where you're hitting by watching where the blood comes out.  If it's coming out of their body, you're aiming too low :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hit them in the head.**

This is more difficult than you would expect, however. The hitbox is extremely strange, and pointing at the head typically hits the zombie in the chest. When standing on objects, such as cars, the inaccuracy of the hitbox seems to be even higher.

Gauge your accuracy by watching for blood splatter and zombie response.

Comment: blood always splatters and zombie response seems to be random.

Comment: The head typically rocks backwards when hit correctly :P

Comment: haha alright ill see if i notice a difference